# WordNet-based Semantic Similarity (WNetSS) API

Tags: java, netbeans, semantics, similarity, wordnet

I'm using [WNetSS](http://wnetss-api.smr-team.org/) API in my research to calculate semantic similarity between words. I followed their instructions listed in [this page](http://wnetss-api.smr-team.org/files/Readme.txt). I run the [first example](http://wnetss-api.smr-team.org/Examples/Example0.java) and it worked perfectly and the database has loaded successfully, but when I tried to run the [second example](http://wnetss-api.smr-team.org/Examples/Example1.java), this error has been shown:

```
run:
The database WordnetSemanticSimilarity is created.
Feb 13, 2018 11:34:07 PM net.sf.extjwnl.dictionary.Dictionary setInstance
INFO: Installing dictionary net.sf.extjwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary@e73f9ac
Loading WordNet2.1 in progress ...
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1740-noun' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2450)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2371)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2355)
    at WordNetSemanticSimilarity.WordNetTreatment.WordNetProcessing.LoadWordNetInDataBase(WordNetProcessing.java:259)
    at wnetssexamples.Example0.main(Example0.java:39)
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I tried to open the created DB from the first example and I found that there four rows have the same key value, but not sure if this is will change the logic of the api:

[image]

When I tried further to find how many duplicated rows in that table I found a huge number as shown in the following figure:

[image]

Please I'm not sure how to fix this issue since I didn't create the DB myself I'm just loading it. Not sure if this is the author's fault or I did something wrong. Your fast response will help a lot.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you runned example 0 twice which will duplicate records in the dataset, what should be done is run example 0 , then example 1 run it four time each with changing the following line:

For the first time `POS pos=POS.ADVERB;` 
The second time `POS pos=POS.ADJECTIVE;`
The third time `POS pos=POS.NOUN;`
The fourth time `POS pos=POS.VERB;`

Then run example 6 four times with the same modifications done in example 1.

Then try to comment these classes and never run them again so the database and tables will not be overwritten.